# Can anyone explain this function?

Tags: php, bitwise-operators

It is a simple program to find out if an integer is a power of 4, but I couldn't understand this section when we take integer  255 & 256:

```
 $x = $n;
              while ($x % 4 == 0) {
              $x /= 4;
             }

            if($x == 1)
```

Can someone explain it to me?

```
<?php
    function is_Power_of_four($n)
    {
          $x = $n;
          while ($x % 4 == 0) {
          $x /= 4;
         }

        if($x == 1)
        {
            return "$n is power of 4";
        }
        else
        {
            return "$n is not power of 4";
        }

    }
    print_r(is_Power_of_four(4)."\n");
    print_r(is_Power_of_four(255)."\n");
    print_r(is_Power_of_four(256)."\n");
  ?>
```

Comment: Look  up [bitwise operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

Comment: For me that duplicate is too narrow. This question is more about a particular use of the bitwise AND operator.

Comment: I know Bitwise operator But it was used for find if a integer is power of 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's idiomatic in older languages like C.

A number `x` greater than 1 that is a power of two will have an binary representation `1 0 ...` where `...` is any number of zeros.

One less than a number that's a power of two (`x - 1`, say) will have the binary representation `1 ...` where `...` is any number of ones. Furthermore it will have one fewer binary digit than `x`. It's also obvious that a subtraction of one from a power of 2 flips all the bits in that original number: no other number has this property.

`&` is the bitwise AND operator. Reference http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Hence `x & (x - 1)` will be 0 if and only if `x` is an exact power of 2.

Comment: Can you be more specific from  line 3 ? 

I didn't understand the line from - "One less than a number  That's a ........... power of two (x-1, say) will have.......

Comment: E.g. take 16. That is 0b10000. 15 is 0b1111. 0b10000 & 0b1111 is 0.